# How to render a non english characters (japanese, chinise) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding, character-encoding

I know my issue already have a solution in here. but i just want to be specific in my case. i have a json object that has a non-english characters in it.

**eg. {"my_chinise_name" : "吉米" }**.

this object will be render via javascript (jquery). somethig like this **$("input").val(object.my_chinise_name)**

currently im receving this iconic random string �¹ã�¼ã��ã�¼ã�¡ã�¬ã�¦ã�«ã��ã�©ã�ªã�

Im not really confident on how html, php encoding works and i've done my research sadly none of them worked. Hope the community can help me with this. thank you very much

Comment: you just need to set header meta charset utf8. [try this](http://jsbin.com/banavelexu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two things should get you set. Inside the `<head>` of your HTML, you should have a `meta` tag to specify UTF-8 charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and on the PHP side (before any HTML output):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i already added this tags and the function, i know that i'm telling to my file that it should use the characters that in UTF-8 standard, my question is does not browser knows these characters, if not to convert (encode) them to its original characters

Comment: That's strange. Are you getting these values from a database? If you look at the network request, do you see the Chinese characters or do you see tofu? Can you verify that the `Content-Type` header on the page is what you set it to and not being hijacked?

Comment: Great, cant believe that was very simple. the issue was the framework im using. it seems the fframework. encodes my string to a different format causing the characters unreadable by the browser. what i did create a service that will get the string directly from the database not from the framework. perfectly smooth after that.

Thanks for your help. really appriciate it